# Multiple testing scanf result - C

Tags: c, scanf

I am new in c programming and i need to scan variable if variable is EOF or non-number.

My code is this:

```
 while (scanf("%d", &var) != EOF) {
code...
  }
```

I need something like this:

```
while ((scanf("%d", &var) != EOF)||(scanf("%d", &var) != 1)) {
    code...
      }
```

Problem is that when i use scanf once it will scan input and second scanf waits for next input and wont test the actual one.

Thank for any help.

Comment: scanf moves the input cursor in the FILE *, you need to put it back so it can be scanned again. or scan as a string and handle internally

Comment: how can i do that ? or better how can i find if (int var) is number or smthing else ?

Comment: Don't you mean `&&` rather than `||`? The latter is always true, because if it's EOF then it's not 1, and vice versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the result of `scanf` in a variable so you can test it again.

```
while ((res = scanf("%d", &var)) != EOF && res != 1) {
    code ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You better work at char level and store the data to check later, something like this:

```
    unsigned char buf[256];
    unsigned int p=0;
    unsigned char c;
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
        buf[p++]=c;

    buf[p]=0;
```

p is the length of recorded data